# Webapp established in Azure App service environment does not load from internet and only loads on backbone network

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a WebApp established in the Azure Isolated plan for Azure App service environment (ASE). There are other websites too that load from the internet in the same App service environment but my website does not load (over the internet, it loads in intranet) even after setting up a DNS record for my website URL to internal load balancer of ASE like other websites.

Is there something else to be configured somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the app within an ILB ASE? ILB ASE apps are internet-isolated back-end apps, which your front-end apps can securely integrate with. It is not exposed to internet and works within intranet environment. You can go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) documentation.